# UIPickerView with null data

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:picker1];

        picker1.delegate=self;
        picker1.dataSource=self;
        picker1.tag = 1;

       Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             [self  webservice];

    }
    -(void)webservice
    {


        NSLog(@"dropdown method is call");

        NSString *envalope=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                            "<soap:Body>\n"
                            "<ShowValue xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                            “</ShowValue>\n"
                            "</soap:Body>\n"
                            "</soap:Envelope>"];

        envalope=[NSString stringWithFormat:envalope];
        NSData *envelope = [envalope dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *url=@"http://ShowService.asmx";

        NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

        [request2 addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/ShowValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request2 setHTTPBody:envelope];
        [request2 setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request2 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [envelope length]]forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        NSURLConnection *connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self];
        if (connection1){
            resservice = [NSMutableData data];
            NSLog(@"connection Establish.");

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"NSURLConnection initWithRequest: Failed to return a connection.");
        }

    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {


        [resservice setLength:0];

    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {


       [rresservice appendData:data];

    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

        NSString *theXml1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[ resservicemutableBytes] length:[ resservice length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"The final result 1--- :%@",theXml1);



        NSArray * jsonarr1 =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[theXml1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"print array :%@",jsonarr1);
        for (NSDictionary * d in jsonarr1)
        {
            if ([d objectForKey:@"SH"]!=[NSNull null])
            {
                [picker1 reloadAllComponents];
                self.shapestring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[d objectForKey:@"SHP"]];
                NSLog(@"pVALUE FOR :%@",self.shapestring);
                [_customPickerArrayshap addObject:self.shapestring];
                NSLog(@"pVALUE AFTER ARRAY FILL:%d",_customPickerArrayshap.count);
                [picker1 reloadAllComponents];
                NSLog(@"Array for shape%@",_customPickerArrayshap);

            }

        if(xmlParser1)
        {

        }
        xmlParser1 = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: resshap];
        [xmlParser1 setDelegate:self];
        [xmlParser1 setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
        [xmlParser1 parse];
        //[theXml release];
    }
    }
    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
        if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"ShowResult"])
        {
            if (!soapResults1)
            {
                soapResults1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            }
            elementFound1 = YES;
        }
    }
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {
        if (elementFound1)
        {
            [soapResults1 appendString: string];

            NSArray * jsonarr1 =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"print array :%@",jsonarr1);
            for (NSDictionary * d in jsonarr1)
            {
                if ([d objectForKey:@"SH"]!=[NSNull null])
                {
                [picker1 reloadAllComponents];
                    self.shapestring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[d objectForKey:@"SH"]];

                  [picker1 reloadAllComponents];
                }
                else
                {self.shapestring=@"";
                                }
            }
        }
            i        }
        }


    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
     namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShowResult"])
        {



                   [soapResults1 setString:@""];
            elementFound1 = FALSE;
        }
    }
    - (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
            return 1;
        }
    - (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
            return Array.count;

    }
    - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
            return _Array[row];

    }
    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
           [self.Array objectAtIndex:row];


    }
```

error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

In my IOS Application Programming,I'm getting soap response from server then parse soap response in array and assign array to PickerView, then nothing is add in UIPickerView and Following error Occure and application is crashed.Even response come from server is ok and also add in array.here i'm getting response from server than assign it to an array.response also valid getting from server not null.

Comment: can you give source code?

Comment: please check edited source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As datasource for picker is "Array"

Replace

```
[_customPickerArrayshap addObject:self.shapestring];
```

With

```
[Array addObject:self.shapestring];
```